# How to read environment variable from .env file using Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bash, security

In order to keep api key secret and not hard coding them in code I have created .env file where I have set the value of key shown below. Now I want to inject this value during build time.

1 `.env` file

```
API_KEY="2131224"
```

2 I have also added the following run script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Show env vars
grep -v '^#' .env

# Export env vars
export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)
```

3 During compile time I am able to see the `API_KEY` in logs, But I don’t know how to assign it to var during api call.

[image]

I tried to access value using ProcessInfo, but it did not work.

```
ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["API_KEY"]
```

Any idea how can I access this?

Comment: This is tagged `iOS`, but you don't get control of env vars of iOS apps running on device

Comment: Thanks Alexander for editing the question and making it more readable, I am exploring other things to keep api keys hidden and secret.

Comment: The only way to keep API keys truly secret is to have a backend service that calls the API on your client's behalf. Think about it: if your end users have to query the API, so they need the API key _somewhere_. That's exactly contrary to the goal of them not having the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Environment Variables for Xcode by

`Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Arguments > Environment Variables`

[image]

But this won't affect your production app, they won't be included when you archive, they are only included when you run the app via to Xcode.

They stay with Xcode/project and therefore visible to anyone that has access to your project.

A production app shouldn't include API Keys they belong Server side somewhere and inside something like "Secret manager"

https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will explore google secret manager.